# i have a weird error LNK2001 when trying to seperate my main function into a main.cpp

Tags: c++

When I try creating an object in Visual studio i get a weird error LNK2001 , i can compile each cpp file by itself and i have no problems running the code when i use the main() function inside the city.cpp file and not use a main.cpp , here are the codes , please help me i can't find an answer anywhere
I'm new to c++ and visual studio , this might be a basic error but i've spent long hours without finding a solution

-----main.cpp-----

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>    
#include <array>       
#include <ctime>        
#include <random>     
#include "math.h"
#include "City.h"
#include "Path.h"



int main()
{
City city = City(0, 5, 10); // simple test
std::cout << city.GetX() << std::endl;
std::cin.get();
}
```

----City.cpp----

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include "math.h"


class City
{
private:
    unsigned int             m_Id;
    int                      m_X;
    int                      m_Y;
    std::array<float, 29>    m_Distances;

public:

    City()
        :m_Id(0), m_X(0), m_Y(0)
    {

    }

    City(unsigned int id, int x, int y)
        : m_Id(id), m_X(x), m_Y(y)
    {
    }

    const unsigned int GetID() const
    {
        return m_Id;
    }

    const int GetX() const
    {
        return m_X;
    }

    const int GetY() const
    {
        return m_Y;
    }


    const float GetDistanceTo(unsigned int index) const
    {
        return m_Distances[index];
    }

    const void updateDistances(const std::array<City, 29>& cities) 
    {
        unsigned int i = 0;
        for (const City& city : cities)
        {
            m_Distances[i++] = (float)round(sqrt(pow((m_X - city.GetX()), 2) + pow((m_Y - city.GetY()), 2)));
        }
    }


};
```

---- City.h ----

```
#pragma once
#define PATH_SIZE 29;

class City
{
    unsigned int            m_Id;
    int                     m_X;
    int                     m_Y;
    std::array<float, 29>   m_Distances;

public:
    City(unsigned int id, int x, int y);
    City();
    const int GetX() const;
    const int GetY() const;
    const unsigned int GetID() const;
    const float GetDistanceTo(unsigned int index) const;
    const void updateDistances(const std::array<City, 29>& cities) ;
};
```

> 1>------ Build started: Project: TSPV1, Configuration: Debug Win32
>   ------   1>City.cpp   1>main.cpp   1>Generating Code...   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   City::City(unsigned int,int,int)" (??0City@@QAE@IHH@Z) referenced in
>   function   _main   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol "public: int const  __thiscall City::GetX(void)const "
>   (?GetX@City@@QBE?BHXZ) referenced in function _main

Comment: The City class should be declared in the header file only. Which C++ textbook are you learning this stuff from?

Comment: Unrelated When returning by value there isn't much point to making the value `const`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth i didn't use any textbook , i just assumed things worked this way , i have some background using Java. thank's for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

In your Code you define the class `City` two times, ones in City.h and ones in City.cpp. What you really want to do is to split up your `City` class into declaration and definition.

Therefore you should have one header file City.h where you declare the `City` class. It could look like:

```
#ifndef CITY_H // These macros ensure that your
#define CITY_H // class is only defined ones.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <math.h>

#define PATH_SIZE 29 // replaced the occurrence of 29 in your code by this macro and removed ';'

class City
{
private:
    unsigned int            m_Id;
    int                     m_X;
    int                     m_Y;
    std::array<float,PATH_SIZE>  m_Distances;

public:
    City(unsigned int id, int x, int y);
    City();
    const int GetX() const;
    const int GetY() const;
    const unsigned int GetID() const;
    const float GetDistanceTo(unsigned int index) const;
    const void updateDistances(const std::array<City,PATH_SIZE> &cities) ;
};

#endif
```

A second source file City.cpp should define your class:

```
#include "City.h"

City::City()
    :m_Id(0), m_X(0), m_Y(0)
{

}

City::City(unsigned int id, int x, int y)
    : m_Id(id), m_X(x), m_Y(y)
{
}

const unsigned int City::GetID() const
{
    return m_Id;
}

const int City::GetX() const
{
    return m_X;
}

const int City::GetY() const
{
    return m_Y;
}


const float City::GetDistanceTo(unsigned int index) const
{
    return m_Distances[index];
}

const void City::updateDistances(const std::array<City,PATH_SIZE>& cities) 
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (const City& city : cities)
    {
        m_Distances[i++] = (float)round(sqrt(pow((m_X - city.GetX()), 2) + pow((m_Y - city.GetY()), 2)));
    }
}
```

You now can include City.h in your main.cpp and start using the class.

Comment: I would add a short explanation that OP right now has **two** classes called `City`, one that is never used (in the cpp) and one that doesn't have method bodies (in the header). I think that would help OP understand why their code isn't equivalent to your solution. Otherwise +1